# Excel: get subarray from column with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique, excel-365

I'm sorry I'm new to Excel, so I'm asking questions that I could probably Google if I new enough terminology to come up with a good search phrase.

Here's a simplification of my problem:

Using this table, I need to get the UIDs (and then the corresponding names, but that's easy) of every active player on "Team A":

[image: source_table]

Therefore, my result table should look like this:

[image: result_data]

The problem is unique-ness.

It's easy to find the UID using the conditions 'column C cells must have "Team A"' and 'column D must be TRUE"'... I find good old Arthur's UID, the first on the list.

Then I drag whatever formula down to the rest of the column, I find... Arthur's UID again (I've used VLOOKUP, INDEX/MATCH and XLOOKUP among others).  I can't figure out how to get a result and then ignore that result after I've populated a cell with it.

How do I do this?

*note I'm using Office 365 (in case there are non-backward-compatible formulas)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FILTER:

```
=FILTER(A:B,(C:C="Team A")*(D:D=TRUE))
```

Comment: nice - also, =FILTER(A:B,(C:C="Team A")*(D:D)), right?

Comment: @markfitzpatrick yes, I just find it easier when helping others to explicitly set it, it avoids a misunderstanding.

Comment: Ah.... FILTER( )!  Good stuff!  Let me ask you this:  what's the deal with the asterisk between the two statements in the second arg?  C:C="Team A")  ASTERISK (D:D=TRUE)   What is it doing there?

Comment: @Bob it means `AND` if we wanted `OR` it would be `+`

Comment: Change the first reference to the column you want output.

Comment: Ah!  Got it!   Thanks!  Wow, this function just made my day's job a breeze!